# How to get source and header files

Tags: c, shared-libraries, header-files

I am working on one full duplex communication project in that we requires files as:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>,
#include <sys/socket.h>,
#include <netinet/in.h>
```

when I write program without these file I get error:

> ../development/src/../include/gxobjects.h:1604:14: error: field
> 'primaryDNSAddress' has incomplete type
> IN6_ADDR primaryDNSAddress;
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ../development/src/../include/gxobjects.h:1605:14: error: field
> 'secondaryDNSAddress' has incomplete type
> IN6_ADDR **secondaryDNSAddress**;
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

when I declaree `IN6_ADDR`.

Please give me link from where I can get these files.

Comment: I believe you need `libc6-dev`

Answer (score 0):

My search engine gave me as first result:

[IN6_ADDR structure (in6addr.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/in6addr/ns-in6addr-in6_addr)

My answer would be, that you have to include the `in6addr.h` header file.

Answer (score 0):

I have One C code and want that code to transfer in Embedded C. I have problem in IP address. I just added all hex and source files in MPLAB X and It shows error as:

```
    In file included from ../development/src/../include/objectarray.h:41:0,
                 from ../development/src/../include/dlmssettings.h:42,
                 from ../development/src/../include/apdu.h:36,
                 from ../development/src/apdu.c:37:
../development/src/../include/gxobjects.h:42:20: fatal error: in6addr.h: No such file or directory
 #include<in6addr.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [build/default/production/_ext/530717503/apdu.o] Error 255
```